# How to Bind a data member to Drop DownList when Using RadGrid control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, binding, telerik

I have a RadGrid control and I'm defining the Edit Form for it.

I have added a text box to bind data to as below which works fine:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="tbAuthenticationMode" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("AuthenticationMode") %>' CssClass="tbAuthenticationMode">
                                    </asp:TextBox>
```

Now, I'd like to remove this text box and replace it with a simple drop down list as below:

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlAuthenticationMode" runat="server">
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="Windows Authentication" Value="Windows"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="SQL Server Authentication" Value="SqlServer"></asp:ListItem>
                                    </asp:DropDownList>
```

What I'd like to happen is that the "AuthenticatioMode" value to be bound to this drop down list.

How would it be possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must first override the RadGrid's `ItemCreated` event. Then check if the event's item editable and en edit mode. Then you can bind data to it. Here's a code sample:

```
protected void RadGrid1_ItemCreated(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Item is GridEditableItem && e.Item.IsInEditMode)
   {
      GridEditFormItem geiEditedItem = e.Item as GridEditFormItem;
      geiEditedItem.Visible = true;

      //Edit mode
      if (e.Item.DataItem is YourClass)
      {
         YourClass currentItem = (YourClass)e.Item.DataItem;

         DropDownList ddlAuthenticationMode= geiEditedItem.FindControl("ddlAuthenticationMode") as DropDownList;
         ddlAuthenticationMode.SelectedValue = currentItem.AuthenticatioMode.ToString();
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: thanks; do you know how I can call a javascript function when the value is bound to my drop down list? based on the value which is bound, I'd like to show or hide some other elements using javascript.

Comment: @William: in the ´RadGrid1_ItemDataBound´ event you can switch-case for the value of the ´e.Item´ and then call some javasript functions you defined. Use the ´ScpriptManager´ od ´RadScpriptManager´ for registering javascript functions. This is not a simple thing, so ti's best if you post the question as a separate question, or ask it at the telerik forums. Here's a link that can be helpful: http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/grid/hide-show-gridcheckboxcolumn-in-itemdatabound.aspx